# How display data entered in one text box to another text box on checkbox tick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to reflect data entered in one text box to another text box on checkbox tick. The default state of checkbox is checked. The value should change after it is unchecked and gets checked back again. Even though the code seems to be working, the only output I'm getting is 'on'.

```js
$(".check").click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $('.add1').val(this.value) === $('.add2').val(this.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=checkbox checked class="check">
<input type="text" id="first" class="add1" />
<input type="text" id="second" class="add2" />
```

Kindly note that I would like to do this by class.

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/starscream166/n87vLd51/1/

Comment: `The value should change after it is unchecked ` which value?

Comment: There is only a if part of the loop which will get executed for one. There is no else part which says what should be done on the other hand.

Comment: @Cooper you want to change in text of second input on **change in input** or **changing of checkbox**

Comment: The value entered in the text box. What I meant is that 'checked' is the default state of the checbox. On unchecking , nothing is to be performed and on checking it back, the value entered in the first text box must be reflected in the second one.

Comment: On changing of checkbox, Maheer Ali.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check here: https://jsfiddle.net/4kp3msax/1/
OR you can do the following code.

```
 $(".check").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      var add1 = $('.add1').val();
      $('.add2').val(add1);
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue is because `this` refers to the `checkbox`. Hence `this.value`, which you place in the value of the textboxes, it the string 'on'.

To fix this place the `val()` of `.add1` in to `.add2`, as in the below example. Also note the use of `change` instead of `click` when dealing with checkboxes, as it improves accessibility.

```js
$(".check").change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('.add2').val($('.add1').val());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" checked class="check">
<input type="text" id="first" class="add1" />
<input type="text" id="second" class="add2" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Pass `$('.add2').val()` the result of `$('.add1').val()`

`.val()` can be used to retrieve or assign an input's value. It can be called without a parameter, which will return the string value of the input. Or, it can be called with a parameter which will assign the value to the input.

```js
$(".check").click(function() {

  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $('.add2').val($('.add1').val());
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=checkbox checked class="check">
<input type="text" id="first" class="add1" />
<input type="text" id="second" class="add2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Works when any of one field data changed

```js
let swt_data = "";
$(".add1").on("change", function() {
  swt_data = $(this).val();
})

$(".check").click(function() {

  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    if (swt_data != $('#first').val() != $('#second').val()) {
      $('#first').val(swt_data);
      $('#second').val(swt_data)
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=checkbox checked class="check">
<input type="text" id="first" class="add1" />
<input type="text" id="second" class="add1" />
```